Struggling to migrate from Windows
I am very much a novice. I have a 12 year old computer that I'm trying to migrate from Windows 10 to Ubuntu Studio 24.04. After some struggles, I was able to get an install working for several days. As long as I shut it down it would restart, but if it went to sleep it wouldn't wake properly. I had lights and fans going, but my monitor was in sleep mode. it required a restart to get things going again. Other than that it seemed to be working.
I tried to use Wine to run a couple of programs I'm used to, and when they didn't work I attempted to uninstall them. I was getting an error in the terminal... something to do with Nvidia driver 'randr' or something, and was given the suggestion to use the foss driver instead. I tried that, and after trying to restart, I had a similar issue to the sleep mode problem, but the monitor was not in sleep mode.
After several attempts to restart the system, I tried a couple times to do a fresh install of the OS but I keep ending up with a screen showing Window 7, Windows 10, and Windows 7 as the only boot options... none of which work.
I'd really like to completely divorce myself from Windows, but I'm feeling dumber by the minute.

First impression of Ubuntu is based upon your computer. Mine is more than 15 yrs. old and it is a desktop, It has intel processor and no NVIDIA, therefore I didn't have to fix anything, it worked right out of the box. To run programs with wine is not a goos idea if you just started using Ubuntu try to find Linux alternatives. If you post the errors it is possible you get an answer that will help. Post them as a text not as a picture.

And please read this https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Your question is written more as a story, and if there was a clear problem you want solved I don't see it. There should be a single problem (the question) but you mention kernel issue on awaking from sleep, then switch to a wine which is a user-app and not involved in sleep??  This is not a forum don't forget; but a Q&A or Question and Answer site, one clearly defined question (ie. the problem) that people can write answers too. https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums (if you want a forum format)

To start with. Edit the question and add your hardware info. Do some research as to what the min hardware for the OS requires. It is doubtful that a 12 year old machine runs a brand new OS. There are other flavors of Ubuntu like Lubuntu that might be a better choice.

FYI:  The oldest device I have and use in QA is a 2005 HP Compaq... so old hardware can run, but GPU or graphics hardware can sometimes be problematic with some kernels..  You give no details as to your hardware, so we can't offer suggestions relating to that... Don't worry about feeling dumb; WE ALL ARE !!! (thankfully not all the time!) and further most of us learn, and the frequency of our dumbness reduces....  We all started with little to no knowledge anyway, so no need to apologize/explain.  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu anyway.
